# Identifying a subclass given a pointer to its base class?

Tags: c++, dynamic-typing

Suppose that I have an abstract base class Parent and subclasses Child1 and Child2. If I have a function that takes a Parent*, is there a way (perhaps with RTTI?) to determine at runtime whether it's a Child1* or a Child2* that the function actually received?

My experience with RTTI here, so far, has been that when foo is a Parent*, typeid(foo) returns typeid(Parent*) regardless of the child class that foo's a member of.

Comment: A `Parent*` is always a `Parent*`. It is *never* a `Child*`. What you mean to ask is "what is the type of the thing it points to".

Comment: Kerrek SB: I gave you the cold shoulder yesterday, but when I got around to the actual programming, your comment was probably more valuable than anything else on the page. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to look at the typeid of the dereferenced pointer, not the pointer itself; I.e., typeid(*foo), not typeid(foo). Asking about the dereferenced pointer will get you the dynamic type; asking about the pointer itself will just get you the static type, as you observe.

Comment: That sounds like a more exact fit with what I'd been looking for than creating numerous subclass pointers would've been...

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `typeid(*foo)` will only return the correct runtime type (i.e `Child1` instead of  `Parent`) if the parent class has at least one virtual method.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `std::dynamic_cast` for this.

```
Parent* ptr = new Child1();
if(dynamic_cast<Child1*>(ptr) != nullptr) {
    // ptr is object of Child1 class
} else if(dynamic_cast<Child2*>(ptr) != nullptr) {
    // ptr is object of Child2 class
}
```

Also if you are using smart pointers, like `std::shared_ptr`, you can check it like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Parent> ptr(new Child1());
if(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Child1>(ptr) != nullptr) {
    // ptr is object of Child1 class
} else if(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Child2>(ptr) != nullptr) {
    // ptr is object of Child2 class
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
BaseClass *bptr = // whatever, pointer to base class
SubclassOne *safe_ptr_one = dynamic_cast<SubclassOne *>(bptr);
if (safe_ptr_one != nullptr) {
    // Instance of SubclassOne
} else {
    // not an instance of SubclassOne, try the other one
    SubclassTwo *safe_ptr_two = dynamic_cast<SubclassTwo *>(bptr);
    if (safe_ptr_two != nullptr) {
        // Instance of SubclassTwo
    } else {
        // it wasn't either one :'(
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice -- I didn't know dynamic_cast could do that! (But then, that's why I asked.)

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr You're welcome. And yay, I managed to provide an answer before Andy Prowl!